# Soft keyboard on physical device doesn't show when a textbox is clicked

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm currently using Oppo F7 to test my app that I made using Android Studio. However, when I tested it and I clicked on a textbox (or EditText), the keyboard doesn't show/pop-up. Helpppp..

Note: 

- My Oppo F7 is running on Android 8.1.0 (API 27)

- It works on the emulator on my laptop but it's far to laggy for me to test

Comment: add <requestFocus/>this to inside EditText

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
public static void showSoftKeyboard(final Context context, final EditText editText) {
        try {
            editText.requestFocus();
            editText.postDelayed(
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            keyboard.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
                        }
                    }
                    , 200);
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            npe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

in your activity call on text click

```
showSoftKeyboard(this, yourEditTextToFocus);
```